# Accept templated parameter of stl_container_type<string>::iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have a function where I have a container which holds strings (eg `vector<string>`, `set<string>`, `list<string>`) and, given a start iterator and an end iterator, go through the iterator range processing the strings.

Currently the function is declared like this:

```
template< typename ContainerIter>
void ProcessStrings(ContainerIter begin, ContainerIter end);
```

Now this will accept any type which conforms to the implicit interface of implementing `operator*`, prefix `operator++` and whatever other calls are in the function body.

What I really want to do is have a definition like the one below which explicitly restricts the amount of input (pseudocode warning):

```
template< typename Container<string>::iterator>
void ProcessStrings(Container<string>::iterator begin, Container<string>::iterator end);
```

so that I can use it as such:

```
vector<string> str_vec;
list<string> str_list;
set<SomeOtherClass> so_set;

ProcessStrings(str_vec.begin(), str_vec.end());  // OK
ProcessStrings(str_list.begin(), str_list.end());  //OK
ProcessStrings(so_set.begin(), so_set.end());  // Error
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is restrict the function specification to make it obvious to a user of the function what it accepts and if the code fails to compile they get a message that they are using the wrong parameter types rather than something in the function body that XXX function could not be found for XXX class.

Comment: Do you wish to restrict it to `std::string` or any `std::basic_string` type ?

Comment: Ah, someone actually _needs_ __concepts__! Unfortunately, they were thrown overboard last summer at the recommendation of a rather prominent member of the C++ standardization committee, because they delayed the forthcoming of C++0x to the point where the 'x' became a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Why do you NEED to restrict what can call your template? The whole point of the template is enable reuse of well-constructed algorithms.

Comment: @jmucchiello - I guess I don't _need_ to restrict the template. The function code specifies an implicit interface which will reject any non-conforming parameters to it. The problems I see are a) how do I handle parameter types which have implemented methods for the various calls inside `ProcessStrings` (such as `operator*` to dereference the iterator, `operator++` to increment it, and whatever `string` member functions happen to match)? and b) are there any other as effective ways of communicating exactly what parameter types the function expects as the kind of specification I laid out above?

Comment: @jmucchiello: The usual incentive is to state your restrictions more explicitly and to get better error messages for types which don't meet them.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understood it at first glance but the goal of the question is not really the restriction but rather an error message that does not span 7/8 lines and confuse the user. Concepts are the best way to go about it... unfortunately the Boost.Concept documentation is really lacking :/ Using BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG should provide a good enough error message (at least better than a normal error), but it's more restrictive than necessary :)

Comment: @Rodion - Really, that's not your problem. If someone is sending sets of carparts into a ProcessStrings function, they get what they get. Is it really worth your time? How does the You Won't Need It principle apply in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get close to this with a template template parameter:

```
template<template<class> class CONTAINER>
void ProcessStrings(CONTAINER<string>&);
```

This will process a whole container, and give a compile error if it doesn't contain strings.

```
ProcessStrings(str_vec); // OK
ProcessStrings(so_set); // Error
```

If you want to work with iterator ranges, then the best I could manager is

```
template<template<class> class CONTAINER>
void ProcessStrings(typename CONTAINER<string>::iterator, 
                    typename CONTAINER<string>::iterator);
```

Unfortunately, type inference won't work on the function arguments, so you'll have to explicitly give the template parameter:

```
ProcessStrings<vector>(str_vec.begin(), str_vec.end()); // OK
ProcessStrings<set>(so_set.begin(), so_set.end()); // Error
```

Can anyone improve on this?

Comment: I would be surprised it worked, using `template <class> CONTAINER` is messy because you need to specify the exact number of template parameter and not only there are several arities depending on which container we're talking about but there's also the issue that a STL implementation may add some supplementary parameters as long as they have proper defaults....

Comment: @Matthieu: I'm pretty sure template argument deduction can fill in default arguments to find a match. Certainly, this code worked when I tested it with gcc.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement such checks using `boost::enable_if` template magic. The method below will not be compiled unless the iterator's value type is of type string.

```
template<class It>
boost::enable_if_c< 
        boost::is_same< typename boost::iterator_value<It>::type, string >::value
>::type
ProcessStrings(It itBegin, It itEnd) 
{ }
```

If `boost::iterator_value<It>::type` is of type string, `boost::enable_if<...>::type` will evaluate to void, your return parameter. Otherwise, due to the SFINAE (substitution-failure is not an error) principle, the method will not be compiled without an error.

Comment: Either `enable_if` or a `static_assert` within the function body should work. Remove the `void` return type (it's `enable_if`'s job to specify it here).

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks, you're right. The void return value was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but effective way.

```
template <class T>
struct is_basic_string: boost::mpl::false_ {};

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc>
struct is_basic_string< std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc> >:
   boost::mpl::true_ {};
```

And then use it to check the value type

```
void ProcessStrings(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG(
    is_basic_string< typename boost::value_type<Iterator>::type >,
    ONLY_ACCEPT_ITERATOR_TO_BASIC_STRING,
    (Iterator)
  );

  // do your work
}
```

Check the reference [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html), this macro is meant to provide as meaningful messages as possible at compilation time.

Also this is slightly more generic than `Sebastian` solution... but `std::wstring` are quite handy for internationalization and you would not want to choke on that.

Now the very good question is... why would you want to do that!

The very goal of generic programming is to produce functions which can work with any type that complies to the operations they use internally. Why do you want to intentionally restrict this ?

Comment: Thanks for the extra details about using `basic_string`, an interesting extention to the question. I have responded to a comment by @jmucchiello on the original question that I hope provides some sort of explanation for your question in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<template<typename T,typename A> class C>
void ProcessStrings(typename C<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::iterator begin,
                    typename C<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::iterator end)
{
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>    strVec;
    std::list<std::string>      strList;
    std::list<int>              intList;

    ProcessStrings<std::vector>(strVec.begin(), strVec.end());
    ProcessStrings<std::list>(strList.begin(), strList.end());
    ProcessStrings<std::list>(intList.begin(), intList.end());  // This will fail
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on how this answer differs from Mike's? I see it specifies the allocator parameter, but is that really a crucial difference?

Comment: I did not see Mikes when I posted. But I just tried it and I can't seem to get it to work without explicitly specifying all the type parameters in the container template. I do not know if this is my compiler or something else I have not tried to solve the problem too hard.